# AngularJs http request header is not changing

Tags: angularjs, http, authentication, http-headers, http-post

I'm getting a problem when I try to call my WebApi, I need to send in a request header the authorization credentials, but, I'm not getting it up.

My resquest header need to be like this image of the request header generated by my REST tester

```
Authorization:Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

But, when I try to set it on Angular using this code block

```
$http.defaults.headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + credentials;
return $http.post('http://localhost:2703/api/Authenticate');
```

Or this

```
return $http.post('http://localhost:2703/api/Authenticate', {
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials }
});
```

My request header became like this one

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: I've found the problem, I guess. When I added headers to my POST call, the method was changed to OPTIONS, I'm using cross domain. Trying to find out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't resolve my problem using a cross domain request, so, I've configure my Web Api and Web App in the same domain. Doing this, I can change the headers normally and send a post request as I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var header = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials}}
$http.post(url, payload, header)
    .success(function (data) {
       //stuff
    }
```

Comment: Doing this the header continues the same. The authorization was added to "Access-Control-Request-Headers". I guess that I need to add a new header named "Authorization". I really don't know what need to do.